# My website only shows user profiles with the first 2 ID numbers. How can I display all user profiles correctly?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, session, user-profile

I´m doing a website in VB.NET that allows users to create and view profiles. For the first two users, the profile shows perfectly, but for any user with an ID number equal or higher than three it doesn't work. What could be the reason for that and how can I fix it?

This is the code that loads the profile in a webform:

```
    Public Sub cargarPerfil(cnn As SqlConnection, cmd As SqlCommand)

    Dim perfil, nombre, nick, pais, ciudad, codigo, telefono, nacimiento, nivel, tipo1, tipo2 As String
    Dim social, artistico, comercial, rango, titulo1, titulo2, titulo3, foto, credito As String
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As DataTable

    perfil = "SELECT USUARIONOMBREREAL, USUARIONICK, PAISNOMBRE AS PAIS, CIUDADNOMBRE AS CIUDAD, USUARIOCODIGO, USUARIOTELEFONO, USUARIONACIMIENTO, " & _
             "TIPONOMBRE AS TIPO1, NIVELNOMBRE AS NIVEL, USUARIOSOCIAL, USUARIOARTISTICO, USUARIOCOMERCIAL, USUARIOFOTO, USUARIOCREDITO, " & _
             "RANGONOMBRE AS RANGO, TITULONOMBRE AS TITULO1 FROM USUARIO " & _
             "INNER JOIN PAIS ON USUARIO.USUARIOPAIS = PAIS.PAISID " & _
             "INNER JOIN CIUDAD ON USUARIO.USUARIOCIUDAD = CIUDADID " & _
             "INNER JOIN TIPO ON USUARIO.USUARIOTIPO1 = TIPO.TIPOID " & _
             "INNER JOIN NIVEL ON USUARIO.USUARIONIVEL = NIVEL.NIVELID " & _
             "INNER JOIN RANGO ON USUARIO.USUARIORANGO = RANGO.RANGOID " & _
             "INNER JOIN TITULO ON USUARIO.USUARIOTITULO1 = TITULO.TITULOID " & _
             "WHERE USUARIOID = '" & Session(Principal.User.UserID) & "' AND USUARIONICK = '" & Session(Principal.User.UserName) & "'"

    With cmd
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = perfil
        .Connection = cnn
    End With

    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    dt = New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)

    nombre = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("USUARIONOMBREREAL")
    nick = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("USUARIONICK")
    pais = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("PAIS")
    ciudad = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("CIUDAD")
    codigo = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("USUARIOCODIGO")
    telefono = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("USUARIOTELEFONO")
    nacimiento = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("USUARIONACIMIENTO")
    tipo1 = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("TIPO1")
    nivel = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("NIVEL")
    social = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("USUARIOSOCIAL")
    artistico = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("USUARIOARTISTICO")
    comercial = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("USUARIOCOMERCIAL")
    rango = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("RANGO")
    titulo1 = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("TITULO1")
    foto = "~/0/" + nombre + ".jpg"
    credito = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("USUARIOCREDITO")

    dt = Nothing

    perfil = "SELECT TIPONOMBRE AS TIPO2, TITULONOMBRE AS TITULO2 FROM USUARIO " & _
             "INNER JOIN TIPO ON USUARIO.USUARIOTIPO2 = TIPO.TIPOID " & _
             "INNER JOIN TITULO ON USUARIO.USUARIOTITULO2 = TITULO.TITULOID " & _
             "WHERE USUARIOID = '" & Session(Principal.User.UserID) & "' AND USUARIONICK = '" & Session(Principal.User.UserName) & "'"

    With cmd
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = perfil
        .Connection = cnn
    End With

    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    dt = New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)

    tipo2 = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("TIPO2")
    titulo2 = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("TITULO2")

    dt = Nothing

    perfil = "SELECT TITULONOMBRE AS TITULO3 FROM USUARIO INNER JOIN TITULO ON USUARIO.USUARIOTITULO3 = TITULO.TITULOID " & _
             "WHERE USUARIOID = '" & Session(Principal.User.UserID) & "' AND USUARIONICK = '" & Session(Principal.User.UserName) & "'"

    With cmd
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .CommandText = perfil
        .Connection = cnn
    End With

    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    dt = New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)

    titulo3 = dt.Rows.Item(0).Item("TITULO3")

    dt = Nothing

    lblNombre.Text = nombre
    lblNick.Text = nick
    lblPais.Text = pais
    lblCiudad.Text = ciudad
    lblCodigo.Text = codigo
    lblTelefono.Text = telefono
    lblNacimiento.Text = nacimiento
    lblTipo1.Text = tipo1
    lblTipo2.Text = tipo2
    lblNivel.Text = nivel
    lblSocial.Text = social
    lblArtistico.Text = artistico
    lblComercial.Text = comercial
    lblRango.Text = rango
    lblTitulo1.Text = titulo1
    lblTitulo2.Text = titulo2
    lblTitulo3.Text = titulo3
    imgPerfil.ImageUrl = foto
    lblCredito.Text = credito

End Sub
```

This is the code that creates profiles in a different webform:

```
    Private Sub registro(cnn As SqlConnection, cmd As SqlCommand)

    Dim nuevo, nombre, nick, pass, mail, pais, ciudad, codigo, telefono, nacimiento, nivel, tipo1, tipo2 As String
    Dim social, artistico, comercial, rango, titulo1, titulo2, titulo3, foto, contrato As String
    Dim savePathF As String = "F:\ComparteME\ComparteME\0\"
    Dim savePathC As String = "F:\ComparteME\ComparteME\Reconocimientos\"
    Dim fileNameF As String = txtNombreReal.Text + ".jpg"
    Dim fileNameC As String = "Reconocimiento - " + txtNombreReal.Text + ".jpg"
    Dim pathToCheckF As String = savePathF + fileNameF
    Dim pathToCheckC As String = savePathC + fileNameC
    Dim tempfileNameF As String = ""
    Dim tempfileNameC As String = ""

    nuevo = ""

    nombre = txtNombreReal.Text
    nick = txtNick.Text
    pass = txtPassword.Text
    mail = txtMail.Text
    pais = ddlPais.SelectedValue
    ciudad = ddlCiudad.SelectedValue
    codigo = txtCodigo.Text
    telefono = txtTelefono.Text
    nacimiento = txtNacimiento.Text
    nivel = ddlNivel.SelectedValue
    tipo1 = ddlTipo1.SelectedValue
    tipo2 = ddlTipo2.SelectedValue
    foto = ""
    contrato = ""
    social = 0
    artistico = 0
    comercial = 0
    rango = 1
    titulo1 = 0
    titulo2 = 0
    titulo3 = 0

    If (uplFoto.HasFile) Then
        If (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToCheckF)) Then
            Dim counter As Integer = 0

            While (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToCheckF))
                tempfileNameF = counter.ToString() + fileNameF
                pathToCheckF = savePathF + tempfileNameF
                counter = counter + 1
            End While

            If counter > 0 Then
                fileNameF = tempfileNameF
            End If

        End If

        savePathF += fileNameF
        uplFoto.SaveAs(savePathF)

        foto = savePathF
    End If

    If (uplReconocimiento.HasFile) Then
        If (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToCheckC)) Then
            Dim counter As Integer = 0

            While (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToCheckC))
                tempfileNameC = counter.ToString() + fileNameC
                pathToCheckC = savePathC + tempfileNameC
                counter = counter + 1
            End While

            If counter > 0 Then
                fileNameC = tempfileNameC
            End If

        End If

        savePathC += fileNameC
        uplReconocimiento.SaveAs(savePathC)

        contrato = savePathC
    End If

    nuevo = "INSERT INTO USUARIO (USUARIOID, USUARIONOMBREREAL, USUARIONICK, USUARIOPASSWORD, USUARIOENCRIPTADO, USUARIOCORREO, USUARIOPAIS, USUARIOCIUDAD, USUARIOCODIGO, USUARIOTELEFONO, " & _
            "USUARIONACIMIENTO, USUARIOTIPO1, USUARIOTIPO2, USUARIONIVEL, USUARIOSOCIAL, USUARIOARTISTICO, USUARIOCOMERCIAL, USUARIORANGO, USUARIOTITULO1, USUARIOTITULO2, " & _
            "USUARIOTITULO3, USUARIOFOTO, USUARIOCONTRATO) " & _
            "SELECT (ISNULL(MAX(USUARIOID), 0)+1), '" & nombre & "', '" & nick & "', '" & pass & "',  PWDENCRYPT('" & pass & "'), '" & mail & "', " & pais & ", " & ciudad & ", " & codigo & ", " & _
            "" & telefono & ", '" & nacimiento & "', " & tipo1 & ", " & tipo2 & ", " & nivel & ", " & social & ", " & artistico & ", " & comercial & ", " & rango & ", " & _
            "" & titulo1 & ", " & titulo2 & ", " & titulo3 & ", '" & foto & "', '" & contrato & "' FROM USUARIO "

    cnn.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = nuevo
    cmd.Connection = cnn
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cnn.Close()

    lblSuccess.Text = "¡Bienvenido a ComparteME! En un momento se comprobar&aacuten tus datos y tu cuenta ser&aacute; activada. Intenta iniciar sesión."

    tblRegistro.Visible = False
    tblSuccess.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Even when I do the query directly in SQLServer, it only loads the data when ID < 3, not any higher. SQL is like this:

```
    SELECT 
USUARIONOMBREREAL, 
USUARIONICK, 
PAISNOMBRE AS PAIS, 
CIUDADNOMBRE AS CIUDAD, 
USUARIOCODIGO, 
USUARIOTELEFONO, 
USUARIONACIMIENTO, 
TIPONOMBRE AS TIPO1, 
NIVELNOMBRE AS NIVEL, 
USUARIOSOCIAL, 
USUARIOARTISTICO, 
USUARIOCOMERCIAL, 
USUARIOFOTO, 
USUARIOCREDITO, 
RANGONOMBRE AS RANGO, 
TITULONOMBRE AS TITULO1 
FROM 
    USUARIO 
    INNER JOIN PAIS ON USUARIO.USUARIOPAIS = PAIS.PAISID 
    INNER JOIN CIUDAD ON USUARIO.USUARIOCIUDAD = CIUDADID 
    INNER JOIN TIPO ON USUARIO.USUARIOTIPO1 = TIPO.TIPOID 
    INNER JOIN NIVEL ON USUARIO.USUARIONIVEL = NIVEL.NIVELID 
    INNER JOIN RANGO ON USUARIO.USUARIORANGO = RANGO.RANGOID 
    INNER JOIN TITULO ON USUARIO.USUARIOTITULO1 = TITULO.TITULOID 
WHERE 
    USUARIOID = '1' AND USUARIONICK = 'SpuntikPPV'
```

Comment: 'it doesn't work' has to be the most unhelpful comment made in a question on this site. Tell us exactly how it doesn't work. Specify what happens, and what should happen, and post only the code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I mean it doesn't load the data for users with an ID higher than 2. When the ID is 1 or 2 it loads the user´s info from a table in the DB, when it isn't 1 or 2 it says there is no data even though there is.

Answer (score 0):

Since a lot of information is missing, I'm going to guess.

I think one of the tables you are joining to has just two records that join to your first two users.   The other users do not have matching records in the other tables so they are omitted.